# JDBC executeBatch behaviour inside a runnable task upon timeout

Tags: java, multithreading, jdbc

I have a `Runnable` task which performs batch update using `JDBC`. In the main thread, I have created an instance of the runnable task and submitted it to the `ExecutorService`, which gives me a `Future` object. I then block the future object with the get call and also specify a 30 seconds timeout.

The run() method of the runnable task has the following structure:

```
PreparedStatement ps = dbConnection.preparedStatement("query");
//loop and set the parameters and add to batch
int[] updateResult = ps.executeBatch();
```

From the main thread, I access this `updateResult` array, from the runnable task instance, to see which data succeeded with the update and which failed.

Now, the question is, if the thread timed out while the execution is still on `ps.executeBatch()` and didn't update the `updateResult` array, will the database changes be rolled back or persist? (I have auto-commit set to true) If the database changes persist, I will still get the updateResult array as null, which would mean, normally, that none of the data got persisted. So, my program will see it as a failure, when it is not.

According to the answer by assylias, I can close the task by the following code:

```
try{
    future.get(timeout, timeunit); 
}catch(TimeoutException e){
    future.cancel(true);
}
```

Is it possible that `ps.executeBatch()` in the runnable task might have persisted the database changes before the main thread calls `future.cancel(true)`, when the get call is interrupted due to timeout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`future.get(timeout, timeUnit)` will try to retrieve the future's result for the specified amount of time. If the future doesn't complete by the end of the timeout, `get` will throw an exception.

**But the underlying task will not be stopped.**

So unless you cancel the task, `executeBatch` will keep running normally after the timeout expires.

Comment: Ok, so in that case i might have to close the runnable task. So, if I have the code as, future.get(timeout, timeunit); if(!future.isDone()) future.cancel(true); this should kill the task. Is it possible that the executeBatch might have persisted the db updates before the execution in main thread actually calls the future.cancel() ?

Comment: @uneq95 JDBC knows nothing about futures, so unless you explicitly handle cancellation, nothing will be cancelled, and given you use auto-commit it will be committed (and if you do cancel, then exact behavior will depend on the driver as `executeBatch` with auto-commit enabled is implementation-specific whether it commits each statement individually or after batch completion.